# Gifts for an Aveil

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus

The Halacha is that Mishloach Manos is not sent to an Aveil. Suppose a close relative is in Aveilus, can you send them flowers for their birthday? (Sources please)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Nit'ei Gavri'el* on *Avelus* (14:9-14) quotes the following rules [some sources in brackets]:

- No sending gifts to a mourner within 30 days, and 12 months for an orphan [*Ram"a* 385:3]

Exceptions:

- Yes sending gifts to a *bar mitzva* boy in mourning because he was a minor when his mourning period began and because it is a *mitzva* [cf. *Divrei Malki'el* 5:233]
- Yes sending gifts to one's mourning bride or groom before the wedding [*Noda BiY'huda* II Y.D. 208]
- Yes sending gifts to one's mourning wife for *yom tov* and *shalom bayis* [*P'sachim* 109]

See the original for many more sources: [p.1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=114) [p.2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=115)